# Why the answer to this question is False?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

Can some one please explain me why the answer to this question is false. I'm new to python and have fair understanding of Java.

Comment: The end result is basically just the value of `not 33`. See the duplicate.

Comment: Break the units down to whether or not they are "truthy." "Truthy" things are not "falsey," and "falsey" things are `0`, `""`, `False`, and empty sequences. In this case `not 33` is "falsey" (because `33` is truthy and `not` inverts it) and anything `... and False` is false.

Comment: Anything non-0 is evaluated as True in a boolean context, so you have (effectively) "(True or True)" simplifying to True. and a "not True", which is False, making  your entrie expression "True and False", which yields False. I hope that's clear, if not, feel free to leave a comment.